# Change selected row to bold text Silverlight XAML

Tags: silverlight, xaml

I am fairly new to Silverlight development and I am still trying to get my head around MVVM.

I have a data grid which displays a list of results, What I need to have happen, is the text in the row to turn bold on selection.

I have my xaml pages split into structure and style which reference a viewModel.cs page.

I would appreciate any advice or pointers on how to acheive this.

Thank you for your time in looking into my post!

Dave.

Answer (score 0):

you could try something like this :

Xaml :

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionChanged="dataGrid1_SelectionChanged" ItemsSource="{Binding .}" Name="dataGrid1">
```

Code behind :

```
private void dataGrid1_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            foreach (DataGridColumn column in this.dataGrid1.Columns)
            {
                FrameworkElement element = column.GetCellContent(e.AddedItems[0]);
                (element as TextBlock).FontWeight = FontWeights.Bold;

                if (e.RemovedItems.Count > 0)
                {
                    element = column.GetCellContent(e.RemovedItems[0]);
                    (element as TextBlock).FontWeight = FontWeights.Normal;
                }

            } 
        }
```

Hope it helps ;)

Comment: Hey Slyvain, Thanks for your response! I have changed my code to match what you have provided (with the exception of variables etc) However, when I debug the app at the foreach loop, it is showing the contents of the columns as null? I have my columns defined as <sdk:DataGridTextColumn ... /> Any ideas? thanks again for your help!